# How to automate the creation of cache disks for storage gateway with terraform?

Tags: terraform, aws-storage-gateway

I'm automating the creation of a storage gateway in terraform following [1], to follow the best practices of gitops of having every important infrastucture as code. And i have to manually allocate the disk to cache. Has someone been able of automating the creating of cache disks for storage gateway in terraform? If I include the code in [1] it appears the error of `data.aws_storagegateway_local_disk.fg_disk: no results found for query, try adjusting your search criteria`. I tried following [2], using disk path instead, but it appeared the same error. Thanks in advance :)

I forgot, this is the code regarding storage gateway cache disks that I used:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs_att_tf" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdb"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.v_sg_agent_tf.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.sg-agent_tf.id

  depends_on = [aws_ebs_volume.v_sg_agent_tf, aws_instance.sg-agent_tf]

}

data "aws_storagegateway_local_disk" "ld_sg_tf" {
  depends_on = [aws_volume_attachment.ebs_att_tf ]
  disk_path   = "/dev/sdb"
  gateway_arn = aws_storagegateway_gateway.sg_tf.arn
}

resource "aws_storagegateway_cache" "sg_c_tf" {
  disk_id     = data.aws_storagegateway_local_disk.ld_sg_tf.disk_id
  gateway_arn = aws_storagegateway_gateway.sg_tf.arn

  depends_on = [ aws_storagegateway_gateway.sg_tf]
}
```

- [1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/storagegateway_gateway
- [2] https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5589

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using disk_node instead of disk_path, that worked for me :

```
data "aws_storagegateway_local_disk" "ld_sg_tf {
    disk_node = "${aws_volume_attachment.ebs_att_tf.device_name}"
    gateway_arn = "${aws_storagegateway_gateway.sg_tf.arn}"
}
```